# Creating same object twice with different result in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm building a face recognition pipeline using tf-insightface for face embedding. I'm extracting images of cropped faces from a video that I'm feeding into the tf-insightface to embed faces.

Every time I want to embed a face I create a new BaseServer object and run the prediction, but it only runs in the first iteration of the for loop (I have many faces to embed).

Looks like that for some reason objects in self.in_ops are persisted even though I create a new instance of the object with every function call.

Looks like a trivial issue, but I'm unable to resolve it.

### This is how I'm calling the lib

```
import os,sys,inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0,parentdir) 

import cv2
import numpy as np
import importlib  
base_server = importlib.import_module("tf-insightface.models.base_server")
configs = importlib.import_module("tf-insightface.configs.configs")

def embed_face(face):    
    # Read example image
    test_img = face
    test_img = cv2.resize(test_img, configs.face_describer_tensor_shape)

# Define input tensors feed to session graph
dropout_rate = 1.0
input_data = [np.expand_dims(test_img, axis=0), dropout_rate]

# Define a Base Server
srv = base_server.BaseServer(model_fp='/Users/andraz/Documents/šola/diploma/tf-insightface/pretrained/insightface.pb',
                             input_tensor_names=configs.face_describer_input_tensor_names,
                             output_tensor_names=configs.face_describer_output_tensor_names,
                             device=configs.face_describer_device)
# Run prediction
prediction = srv.inference(data=input_data)


# Print results
return prediction
```

---

### Stack trace and error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-61ed406b99dc> in <module>
     21 
     22             # Embed faceial features
---> 23             embedded_face = embed_face(cropped_face)
     24             print("Embedded face")

<ipython-input-12-9bc850f211fc> in embed_face(face)
     25                                  device=configs.face_describer_device)
     26     # Run prediction
---> 27     prediction = srv.inference(data=input_data)
     28 
     29     del srv

~/Documents/šola/diploma/tf-insightface/models/base_server.py in inference(self, data)
     73 
     74         with self.graph.as_default():
---> 75             self._set_feed_dict(data=data)
     76             print('[Base Server] Running inference...')
     77             self.prediction = self.session.run(self.output_ops, feed_dict=self.feed_dict)

~/Documents/šola/diploma/tf-insightface/models/base_server.py in _set_feed_dict(self, data)
     62 
     63     def _set_feed_dict(self, data):
---> 64         assert len(data) == len(self.input_ops)
     65         with self.graph.as_default():
     66             print(self.input_ops)

AssertionError:
```

---

### baseserver.py

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

class BaseServer(object):
    in_progress = False
    prediction = None
    session = None
    graph = None
    frozen = False
    feed_dict = {}
    output_ops = []
    input_ops = []


 def __init__(self, model_fp, input_tensor_names, output_tensor_names, device, frozen=True):
     self.model_fp = model_fp
     self.input_tensor_names = input_tensor_names
     self.output_tensor_names = output_tensor_names
     self.frozen = frozen


     with tf.device(device):
         self._load_graph()
         self._init_predictor()

 def _load_graph(self):
     if self.frozen:
         self._load_frozen_graph()
     else:
         self._restore_from_ckpt()

 def _restore_from_ckpt(self):
     self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
     self.saver.restore(self.session, self.model_fp)

 def _load_frozen_graph(self):
     self.graph = tf.Graph()
     with self.graph.as_default():
         od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
         with tf.gfile.GFile(self.model_fp, 'rb') as fid:
             serialized_graph = fid.read()
             od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
             tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
     tf.get_default_graph().finalize()

 def _init_predictor(self):
     tf_config = tf.ConfigProto()
     tf_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
     with self.graph.as_default():
         self.session = tf.Session(config=tf_config, graph=self.graph)
         self._fetch_tensors()

 def _fetch_tensors(self):
     assert len(self.input_tensor_names) > 0
     assert len(self.output_tensor_names) > 0
     for _tensor_name in self.input_tensor_names:
         _op = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name(_tensor_name)
         self.input_ops.append(_op)
         print(self.input_ops)
         self.feed_dict[_op] = None
     for _tensor_name in self.output_tensor_names:
         _op = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name(_tensor_name)
         self.output_ops.append(_op)

 def _set_feed_dict(self, data):
     assert len(data) == len(self.input_ops)
     with self.graph.as_default():
         print(self.input_ops)
         for ind, op in enumerate(self.input_ops):
             self.feed_dict[op] = data[ind]

 def inference(self, data):
     print(self.input_ops)
     self.in_progress = True

     with self.graph.as_default():
         self._set_feed_dict(data=data)
         print('[Base Server] Running inference...')
         self.prediction = self.session.run(self.output_ops, feed_dict=self.feed_dict)
     self.in_progress = False

     return self.prediction

 def get_status(self):
     return self.in_progress

 def kill_predictor(self):
     # In old version tensorflow
     # session sometimes will not be closed automatically
     self.session.close()
     self.session = None
```